# ZED_wrapper_node launch is not working

Tags: roslaunch, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I installed the zed-wrapper from http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper .

All set up was seems okay, the launch is not working on.
(Regarding the server below, I replaced as *. )

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/jetsonbot$ roslaunch zed_wrapper zed.launch
... logging to /home/nvidia/.ros/log/05889502-d661-11e7-a106-00044b8cc889/roslaunch-tegra-ubuntu-3934.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server */

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7
 * /zed/zed_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/base_frame: zed_center
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/camera_frame: zed_left_camera
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/confidence: 100
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/depth_cam_info_topic: depth/camera_info
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/depth_frame: zed_depth_camera
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/depth_stabilization: 1
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/depth_topic: depth/depth_regis...
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/frame_rate: 60
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/gpu_id: -1
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/left_cam_info_topic: left/camera_info
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/left_raw_topic: left/image_raw_color
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/left_topic: left/image_rect_c...
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/odometry_db: 
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/odometry_frame: map
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/odometry_topic: odom
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/openni_depth_mode: 0
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/point_cloud_topic: point_cloud/cloud...
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/publish_tf: True
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/quality: 1
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/resolution: 2
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/rgb_cam_info_topic: rgb/camera_info
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/rgb_raw_topic: rgb/image_raw_color
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/rgb_topic: rgb/image_rect_color
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/right_cam_info_topic: right/camera_info
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/right_raw_topic: right/image_raw_c...
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/right_topic: right/image_rect_...
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/sensing_mode: 0
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/svo_filepath: 
 * /zed/zed_wrapper_node/zed_id: 0

NODES
  /zed/
    zed_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    zed_wrapper_node (zed_wrapper/zed_wrapper_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [zed_wrapper/zed_wrapper_node]: can't locate node [zed_wrapper_node] in package [zed_wrapper]

process[zed/zed_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [3952]
^C[zed/zed_state_publisher-2] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I am using Jetson TX2 and catkin name is jetsonbot.

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ ls -al '/home/nvidia/jetsonbot/devel/lib/zed_wrapper' 
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 nvidia nvidia 4096 Dec  1 15:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 nvidia nvidia 4096 Dec  1 15:29 ..
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277041/zed_wrapper_node-launch-is-not-working./) by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-12-01**:
well, judging from your Output, the node hasn't been built properly. Have there been any Errors during compilation? Otherwise, check the Output of `find /home/nvidia/jetsonbot/devel -iname *zed*`. If the node is not there, there has been a Problem.

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-12-01**:
Thank you for your commend, the catkin_make was not built properly, Now  I can access the zed node. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, judging from your Output, the node hasn't been built properly. Have there been any Errors during compilation? Otherwise, check the Output of find /home/nvidia/jetsonbot/devel -iname *zed*. If the node is not there, there has been a Problem.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0